# How to listen to Process Up or down events in Java?

Tags: java, linux, process, dbus, systemd

I have a process running using Systemctl, configured it with Restart=always
so that even if process crashes then it will restart by itself without manual intervention. When that process restarts I want to take some action in my java code. I don't want poll the process. is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is. You either poll the process, or you somehow poll the OS. If process belongs to you, then maybe you can make the process to write log in a file, and you use `WatchService` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

`systemd` has a [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) API that you can use to receive event notifications when a unit changes state, including changes to its `ActiveState` property that tells you whether it's currently running.  See [this answer on Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309250/how-to-globally-monitor-systemd-unit-states) for more information.

To use this API from a Java program, you'll need a D-Bus library for Java.  It looks like there's a [DBus-Java library](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/), though it hasn't been updated in a long time.  Alternatively, you might be able to have your Java program invoke the command-line `dbus-send` and/or `dbus-monitor` programs and read their output.